# Store SDateTime in SQL database using Haxe

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, haxe, leaderboard

I'm currently using Haxe to create a database and table for storing game data.

I have a field that will be a timestamp. I'm using the following:

```
class GameData extends Object {
    public var id : SId;
    public var username : SString<32>;
    public var countryA2 : SString<32>;
    public var scoreFor : SInt;
    public var scoreAgainst : SInt;
    public var scoreDifference : SInt;
    public var ts : SDateTime;
}
```

I'm then trying to populate this field by using

```
gameData.ts = Date.now();
```

But all this returns is "Date" and not an actual date in numbers.

I then tried the DateTools.format() class and produced this:

```
DateTools.format(Date.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Which gave me the date/time as follows: 2016-11-25 19:17:13

But then trying to store this in the field just returns an error:

```
String should be sys.db.SDateTime
```

What's the ideal way of storing date/time in an SQL database through Haxe?

Thanks.

Comment: SDateTime is just an alias/typedef for Date according to the Haxe documentation: http://api.haxe.org/sys/db/SDateTime.html

I think you should be able to store the date in the first way you tried to populate it, using `Date.now()`. What is it that returns "Date" (are you tracing it out?) and what target are you using?

Comment: As Sam says.

import sys.db.Types;
class Main{
  static public function main():Void {
      var sdate: SDateTime = Date.now();
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve it now, fresh day seemed to strangely allow Date.now() to work. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

probably you should use gameData.ts.toString() or other Data methods 'to get numbers'
look at https://github.com/ufront/ufront-orm where you find http://old.haxe.org/manual/spod 'still the best resource' for Haxe's sys.db.* DB classes and macros
google for 'haxe SPOD' - 'sys.db package contains also the new version for SPOD' - SPOD related examples may be still sys.db compatible - f.e. [this](https://gist.github.com/cambiata/c0b26ad26772f9412836)